# Setting copyright of ArcGIS Server map service via ArcGIS REST API?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api

Knows someone a possibility to set the copyright of an ArcGIS Server Mapservice via REST API?

Didn't found a property in the JSON but in *ArcGIS Server Manager* you can change the value.

Also I found [How To: Modify the copyright text of a hosted feature service in ArcGIS Online](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000016132) for doing that in ArcGIS Online so I couldn't believe that it is impossible for ArcGIS Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution in Help/Reference of ArcGIS REST API:

You can do this:

`http://server:port/arcgis/admin/services/[<folder>]/<serviceName.serviceType>/iteminfo/edit`
There is a property `"accessinformation"` which is the copyright. The only thing not tested is to have linebreaks. Trying it with `<br />`.